# RecyclerView item deletion not animated properly

Tags: java, android, animation, android-recyclerview

I've got a `RecyclerView` which contains items, obviously. It uses the `DefaultAnimator` for all its animations.
When deleting an item, the deletion is animated, but not as it should be. The issue is that it seems like the size of the list is reduced by one first, then the clicked item is deleted and afterwards all items below are moved upwards by one. Take a look at [this short video](https://vid.me/EoJF) to see what I'm talking about.
The code used for the removal of a item is the following:

```
MainActivity.events.events.remove(listItems.keyAt(0));
notifyItemRemoved(listItems.keyAt(0));
```

Where `MainActivity.events.events` contains the data for the items and `listItems.keyAt(0)` contains the currently selected item.

**What I've tried yet (none of this worked):**

- Made sure there's no other call which interrupts the animation (like `notifyDataSetChanged()`).
- Implemented the above code directly into a `onClickListener` for the items inside the adapter.
- Implemented the data directly into the adapter instead of a different class.
- Replaced the position with `getAdapterPosition()` or a fixed value (i.e. `0`)
- Used `notifyItemRangeRemoved()` after `notifItemRemoved()`.

*Hint: I've got the animation to work previously, but as of today it doesn't work anymore.*

**EDIT:**
If I remove the actual removal command (i.e. `MainActivity.events.events.remove(listItems.keyAt(0));`) from the code snippet given above, the animation is [played correctly](https://vid.me/pPnQ), but the element then isn't actually removed, so *this doesn't solve the problem at all*.

Comment: you need to follow these steps.  1) get the items position you are removing -- 2) if you have an array remove the item from there e.g (arrayList.remove(position);) -- 3) remove item from Recycler (adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);) --- put the whole code on how you delete to look

Comment: That's exactly what I do, as you can see it above. The issue isn't that the animation is not working, it's just not animated correctly as you can see it in the video.